# how can i add same values in 2 different tables

Tags: php, database, wordpress

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to insert data into multiple wordpress tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13169276/unable-to-insert-data-into-multiple-wordpress-tables)

[image]

According to the above diagram I have 2 tables and each table have 1 common column, but the issue is that I have to add the same values in both columns rows. Although `wp_terms.term_id` has auto increment in database. But I am not understanding how I copy and use `wp_terms.term_id` value in `wp_term_taxonomy.term_id`.

I had tried an sql query which i given below:

```
// create a tag
$query = "INSERT INTO $wpdb->terms (name, slug) VALUES (%s, %s)";
$wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare($query, $name, $slug));

// create the relationship 
$query = "INSERT INTO $wpdb->term_taxonomy (term_id, taxonomy) VALUES (%d, %s)";  
$wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare($query, LAST_INSERT_ID, 'post_tag'));
```

But after running this script when I check database through phpmyadmin, i notice that `wp_terms` table filled correctly but `wp_term_taxonomy` > `term_id` column is empty.

**And my Actual codes are:**

```
$file_name = $_FILES['tag_import']['name'];
$file_ext = strtolower(end(explode(".", $file_name)));
$file_size = $_FILES['tag_import']['size'];

if (( $file_ext == "xls" ) && ( $file_size < 500000 )) 
{       
    $data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();
    $data->setOutputEncoding('CP1251');
    $data->read($_FILES['tag_import']['tmp_name']);

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $data->sheets[0]['numRows']; $i++)
    {
        for ($j = 1; $j <= $data->sheets[0]['numCols']; $j++)
        {
            // add the new category 
            $query = "INSERT INTO $wpdb->terms (name, slug) VALUES (%s, %s)";
            $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare($query, $data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][1], $data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][2])); 

            // create the relationship 
            $query = "INSERT INTO $wpdb->term_taxonomy (term_id, taxonomy) VALUES (%d, %s)";  
            $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare($query, LAST_INSERT_ID, 'post_tag'));           
        }
    }
    else  
    {
        echo "<div class='error'><p>Invalid file or file size too big.</p></div>";
    }
}
```

Please guide me how can I do that?

Comment: you should get last inserted id in php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont do much wordpress but from the [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpdb_Class#INSERT_rows) it looks like the last id is only filled on `wpdb` when you use the `insert()` method as opposed to using `query()` like you are doing. And its not a global constant its a class variable.

```
$wpdb->insert('terms', array(
  'name' =>  $data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][1],
  'slug' => $data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][2]
));

$wpdb->insert('term_taxonomy', array(
  'term_id' => $wpdb->insert_id,
  'taxonomy' => 'post_tag'
));
```

Comment: can you please tell me little briefly please,

Comment: Tell you what? I just showed you the code in my answer... Add a link to the docs.

Comment: is there any possible way to check if this term is already exists in the database, so it exists then skip and upload next term?